# phpMyAdminのログイン画面が表示されない

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

初心者です。現在、XcodeとMySQLを繋ぎたくて、調べたところ「phpMyAdmin」が便利だと出てきました。
PHP, Apache はXAMPP(7.1.29-1)で入れました。

そこで以下のサイトを参考に、ダウンロードとインストールは完了しました。

[phpMyAdminのダウンロードとインストール](https://www.dbonline.jp/phpmyadmin/install/index1.html)
phpMyAdminを保存した場所は `Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs` です。

次に、以下のサイトを参考にphpMyAdminへログインしようとしました。

[phpMyAdminへのログイン／ログアウト](https://www.dbonline.jp/phpmyadmin/install/index2.html)

しかし、ログイン用URLhttp://localhost/phpMyAdmin/index.phpをクリックすると、以下の画面になりました。

[image: ログイン画面のエラー]

これはどうすればいいのでしょうか？
私の検索スキルが低く見つけられないのでお助け願います。

Comment: 404NotFoundということはApacheの設定の問題の可能性があるため、Apacheの設定情報を追記できますか？特にlocalhostの設定の部分が重要になるかと思います。

Comment: xamppを使っているなら、別途phpMyAdminを入れなくても入っていませんか？

Comment: @Sieg 入ってました。最初は入れずに行なっていましたが、同じように開かず別でダウンロードして上記ディレクトリに移動して試していました。実はその後ChromeではなくSafariで手動でURLを書いたらログイン画面をスキップしてphpMyAdminへ入ることができました。これはChromeとの相性とかあるんでしょうか？その時のURLは(http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php)　でした。

Comment: @keitaro_so Apacheの設定情報はhttpd.confでしょうか？ServerNameの部分は'ServerName localhost' です。実はその後ChromeではなくSafariで手動でURLを書いたらログイン画面をスキップしてphpMyAdminへ入ることができました。これはChromeとの相性とかあるんでしょうか？その時のURLは(http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php) でした。